# How to reference actual generic type at runtime in a class that sub-classes Generic?

Tags: python-3.x, generics, ros2

Is it possible to get the type that was used to annotate/instantiate a Generic python class at runtime?

I have this class:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Optional

from rclpy.node import Node

from evergreen_integration_testing.timeout import Timeout


from evergreen_common.qos import DEFAULT_HISTORY_DEPTH

T = TypeVar('T')


class TopicMonitor(Generic[T]):
    """
        A class for monitoring a ROS topic for the latest message
    """

    def __init__(self, node: Node, topic_name: str):
        self._subscription = node.create_subscription(
            msg_type=T,
            topic=topic_name,
            callback=self._topic_callback,
            qos_profile=DEFAULT_HISTORY_DEPTH
        )
        self._last_msg: Optional[T] = None

    def _topic_callback(self, msg: T) -> None:
        self._last_msg = msg

    def wait_for_next_message(self, timeout_s: float) -> Optional[T]:
        """
            Waits for the next message to be received on the topic.

            Returns None if the timeout is exceeded.
        """

        current_msg = self._last_msg
        with Timeout(timeout_s) as t:
            while current_msg == self._last_msg and not t.is_timed_out():
                pass

        if current_msg == self._last_msg:
            return None
        return self._last_msg

    def wait_for_first_message(self, timeout_s: float) -> Optional[T]:
        """
            Waits for the first message to be received on the topic.

            Returns None if the timeout is exceeded
            Returns the first message received on the topic otherwise
        """
        if self._last_msg is not None:
            return self._last_msg
        return self.wait_for_next_message(timeout_s)
```

Specifically the function `create_subscription` expects me to give it the type of message that the subscriber callback will expect. This type is already annotated with the TypeVar 'T' and I would like to avoid specifying this type twice (i.e. by passing the type as a parameter to the constructor). Is it possible to get the actual type that 'T' refers to at Runtime?

For more context the site where I instantiate the class looks like this:

```
sim_joystick_commands = TopicMonitor[JoystickControl](self.node, 'joystick_commands')
```

I would like to avoid making this into:

```
sim_joystick_commands = TopicMonitor[JoystickControl](self.node, 'joystick_commands', JoystickControl)
```

Running the code as is gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'TypeVar' has no attribute '_TYPE_SUPPORT' This might be a ROS 1 message type but it should be a ROS 2 message type. Make sure to source your ROS 2 workspace after your ROS 1 workspace.
```

Because I can't just provide 'T' directly since it isn't the actual type I wanted to provide.